# Keyboard always visible in notification

Tags: keyboard, miui, keyboard-shortcuts

I have GTA vice city game in my mobile (Redmi Note 4 running on Nougat and MIUI 9). I have installed and started playing but as you all know the game is not fun without "cheat codes".

So I want to use an onscreen keyboard with which I can type in the cheat codes to play the game. I've already tried the third party keyboards but my phone doesn't give permissions for the application.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you tried granting permissions of the keyboard apps with MiUI permission manager? looks like you need to do that before any 3rd party apps are allowed to  run?

Comment: yes, I did but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Mohammed, as asking for apps (or other off-site resources) is off-topic here, I've slightly altered your question so it won't be "voted to close as off-topic". Should still meet your purpose, I hope :)